# deleting the files thru shell

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell programming.
Basically, I wrote a small script which cleans certain file types in that particular folder when executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "cleaning temp extensions "
find -type f -name '*.pyc' -exec rm -f {} ';' 
find -type f -name '.*.swp' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find -type f -name '*~' -exec rm -f {} ';'
echo "files cleaned!!"
```

But now, I want clean all the files from the folders where this shell script is present.

So for example if I have something like

```
 folderA/  folderB/ folderC/   clean.sh
```

WHen I run this clean.sh it deletes all the file types in folderA folderB and folder C
What modification should I make in this script?
Thanks.

Comment: TO whoever voted for "close".. Can you tell me how this is offtopic..
Just look into the related answers on the side..

Comment: It seems more related to something I would expect a "superuser" to be able to do. It's not personal and wasn't followed with a down-vote. It's just familiarization with common shell tools. Now, if this question were discussing some bash syntax for a loop or a recursive call ... more "programming".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for.

To delete ALL files in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type -f -delete
```

To delete all files in the current directory and all directories underneath it:

```
find . -type -f -delete
```

To delete all files and directories in the current directory:

```
find . -delete
```

If you really want to delete "all the files from the folders where this shell script is present," well that's pretty crazy. Why would you copy a script in to a directory in order to delete files in that directory? If you meant "I wan't to be able to delete files with the specified extensions in a specified directory or directories," then it would work like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find "$@" -type f \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.swp' -o -name '*.~' \) -delete
```

And save this to a directory in your PATH (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`), then you can say:

```
clean.sh folderA folderB folderC
```

Or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine all 3 find commands into one like this:

```
find -type f \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '.*.swp' -o -name '*~' \) -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Now to execute this find in a folderA use:

```
find folderA/ -type f \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '.*.swp' -o -name '*~' \) -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the files, remove the `-name ...` filter:

```
find -type f -exec rm -f {} ';'
```

Obvious warning: be careful with that.